# How can I return asQueryable without LoadSelect?

Tags: c#, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I'm using lastest ServiceStack OrmLite(currently v4.5.6) with C#

I need to return asQueryable from a method, such as;

```
    using (IDbConnection databaseConnection = _databaseFactory.Open())
    {
        SqlExpression<T> sqlExpression = databaseConnection.From<T>();

        IQueryable<T> asQueryable = databaseConnection.LoadSelect(sqlExpression, include)
                                                      .AsQueryable();

        return asQueryable;
    }
```

But as you can see, loadSelect already going to sql server like;
Select PARAMSetc FROM Table

So I just need IQueryable without going to sql server. I did it with Entity Framework, here is the code;

```
public IQueryable<T> GetAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    return _dbSet.Where(predicate);
}
```

And yes, I'm writing a kind of generic repository wrapper and I know repository patterns should not return IQueryable because someone use this method and could make performance errors etc. This is out of my topic right now.

How can I return IQueryable with OrmLite ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OrmLite uses it's own typed API for querying using either [simple lambda expressions](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#querying-with-select) for simple queries:

```
var results = db.Select<Poco>(x => x.Id == 1);
```

Or a Typed `SqlExpression<T>` which provides a [Typed API modeled closely over SQL](http://gistlyn.com/?collection=cd381848f252be2a84f8c239ed0d241b&gist=57e4c4eb133503284ee91a6ab77a3986) which also uses LINQ-like lambda expressions to provide a typed, rich API for querying RDBMS's, e.g:

```
var q = db.From<Track>()
    .Where(x => customYears.Contains(x.Year))
    .And(x => x.Name.Contains("A"))
    .GroupBy(x => x.Year)
    .OrderByDescending("Total")
    .ThenBy(x => x.Year)
    .Take(2);

var results = db.Select(q);
```

OrmLite doesn't implement `IQueryable<T>`, if you need an SQL `IQueryable<T>` implementation you'll need to use an ORM that implements it like EF.

The only way to get an `IQueryable<T>` in any other ORM is to return it convert from a .NET `List<T>` that OrmLite returns, e.g:

```
List<Poco> results = db.Select<Poco>();
IQueryable<Poco> queryable = results.AsQueryable();
```

Answer (score 1):

> I saw a post like this;
>   [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/servicestack/rrCXTsCh5Cw)

Firstly there's no IQueryable or Linq in OrmLite it's pretty much just using SQL or filters.
Methods with "Each" in them return back a lazily evaluated list.

> Generally you just query by passing in a "where sql", "anon types" or
>   full sql, eg:

```
var results = dbCmd.Select<Poco>("Name = {0}", name);
var results = dbCmd.Where<Poco>("Name", name);
var results = dbCmd.Where<Poco>(new { Name = name });
var results = dbCmd.Select<Poco>("Select * from Poco Where Name = {0}", name);
var results = dbCmd.Query<Poco>("Select * from Poco Where Name = @name", new { name });
```

> For building of queries the latest version uses a SqlBuilder class
>   which @samsaffron talks about here:
>   http://samsaffron.com/archive/2011/09/05/Digging+ourselves+out+of+the+mess+Linq-2-SQL+created

You can return a builder class that other code uses to construct the query and then use the builder output in a new dbCmd query, example:

```
var count = dbCmd.QuerySingle<Poco>(count.RawSql, count.Parameters);
var rows = dbCmd.Query<Poco>(selector.RawSql, selector.Parameters);
```

Micro ORM's are not for everyone and if you have existing code using IQueryable, it might be better to just leave it as-is.

Comment: FYI that post from 2011 is woefully out of date. OrmLite has it's own SqlExpression and LINQ provider.